# How can I retrive the protected multiple dimentional array of objects in php

Tags: php, arrays

Actually I am Using the stripe checkout system and after the successful payment I have to store the information in the database..But I am facing the issue that is protected fields.

```
Stripe_Customer Object

(

    [_apiKey:protected] => ------------------
    [_values:protected] => Array
    (
        [id] => cus_58BUXTsLUEyImY
        [object] => customer
        [created] => 1415775664
        [livemode] => 
        [description] => 
        [email] => basic@basic.com
        [delinquent] => 
        [metadata] => Stripe_AttachedObject Object
            (
                [_apiKey:protected] => -----------------
                [_values:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [_unsavedValues:protected] => Stripe_Util_Set Object
                    (
                        [_elts:Stripe_Util_Set:private] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [_transientValues:protected] => Stripe_Util_Set Object
                    (
                        [_elts:Stripe_Util_Set:private] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [_retrieveOptions:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

        [subscriptions] => Stripe_List Object
            (
                [_apiKey:protected] => -------------------
                [_values:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [object] => list
                        [total_count] => 1
                        [has_more] => 
                        [url] => /v1/customers/cus_58BUXTsLUEyImY/subscriptions
                        [data] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Stripe_Subscription Object
                                    (
                                        [_apiKey:protected] => ----------------------
                                        [_values:protected] => Array
                                            (
                                                [id] => sub_58BUHhWam3SGYw
                                                [plan] => Stripe_Plan Object
                                                    (
                                                        [_apiKey:protected] => ------------
                                                        [_values:protected] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [id] => gold
                                                                [interval] => year
                                                                [name] => yearly
                                                                [created] => 1415687816
                                                                [amount] => 34999
                                                                [currency] => usd
                                                                [object] => plan
                                                                [livemode] => 
                                                                [interval_count] => 1
                                                                [trial_period_days] => 
                                                                [metadata] => Stripe_AttachedObject Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [_apiKey:protected] => ------------------------
                                                                        [_values:protected] => Array
                                                                            (
                                                                            )

                                                                        [_unsavedValues:protected] => Stripe_Util_Set Object
                                                                            (
                                                                                [_elts:Stripe_Util_Set:private] => Array
                                                                                    (
                                                                                    )

                                                                            )

                                                                        [_transientValues:protected] => Stripe_Util_Set Object
                                                                            (
                                                                                [_elts:Stripe_Util_Set:private] => Array
                                                                                    (
                                                                                    )

                                                                            )

                                                                        [_retrieveOptions:protected] => Array
                                                                            (
                                                                            )

                                                                    )
```

First I have used like this: `$obj->_values` but nothing happened, blank return I get. After that I have covert the object into array. Then it has been converted in array. And got the response like this

```
Array
(
    [*_apiKey] => --------
    [*_values] => Array
    (
        [id] => cus_58CD1hhGW454545
        [object] => customer
        [created] => 1415778371
        [livemode] => 
        [description] => 
        [email] => basic@basic.com
        [delinquent] => 
        [metadata] => Stripe_AttachedObject Object
            (
                [_apiKey:protected] => -----------------
                [_values:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [_unsavedValues:protected] => Stripe_Util_Set Object
                    (
                        [_elts:Stripe_Util_Set:private] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [_transientValues:protected] => Stripe_Util_Set Object
                    (
                        [_elts:Stripe_Util_Set:private] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [_retrieveOptions:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

        [subscriptions] => Stripe_List Object
            (
                [_apiKey:protected] => s---------------
                [_values:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [object] => list
                        [total_count] => 1
                        [has_more] => 
                        [url] => /v1/customers/cus_58CD1hhGWeX0OA/subscriptions
                        [data] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Stripe_Subscription Object
                                    (
                                        [_apiKey:protected] => --------------------
                                        [_values:protected] => Array
                                            (
```

Now when I tried to use the `[*_values]` index I got he error that is undefined index. After that I have used the foreach() to access the next index then got the response.

```
Array
(
    [id] => cus_58CD1hhGWeX0OA
    [object] => customer
    [created] => 1415778371
    [livemode] => 
    [description] => 
    [email] => basic@basic.com
    [delinquent] => 
    [metadata] => Stripe_AttachedObject Object
    (
        [_apiKey:protected] => s--------------------
        [_values:protected] => Array
            (
            )

        [_unsavedValues:protected] => Stripe_Util_Set Object
            (
                [_elts:Stripe_Util_Set:private] => Array
                    (
                    )
            )

        [_transientValues:protected] => Stripe_Util_Set Object
            (
                [_elts:Stripe_Util_Set:private] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

        [_retrieveOptions:protected] => Array
            (
            )
    )
```

Now I have tried to access the field normally we use. like $variable['id']; then I got the error Illegal string offset 'id' ....Now please let me know How can I use these indexes .....and I also have to fetch the below indexes which are in multidimensional array.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the Stripe objects have a megic getter method. try to use the __get("key") method to retrieve the protected values.

Check out the [Stripe source](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/tree/master/lib/Stripe) to see the magic getters and setters.

Comment: No, @István-Őri it's not the way as I have checked it is not working... 
Thanks for reply